# How can I add text insde svg path?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to add a text inside svg path i copy from figma.

Here is how it's look in figma:

[image]

Here is my code base:

```html
  <svg width="185" height="89" viewBox="0 0 185  89" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text>hello</text>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.87195 4.36808C5 6.07937 5 8.31958 5 12.8V27.4268L0.481487 32.6984C-0.160496 33.4474 -0.160496 34.5526 0.481487 35.3016L5 40.5732V76.2C5 80.6804 5 82.9206 5.87195 84.6319C6.63893 86.1372 7.86278 87.3611 9.36808 88.1281C11.0794 89 13.3196 89 17.8 89H172.2C176.68 89 178.921 89 180.632 88.1281C182.137 87.3611 183.361 86.1372 184.128 84.6319C185 82.9206 185 80.6804 185 76.2V12.8C185 8.31958 185 6.07937 184.128 4.36808C183.361 2.86278 182.137 1.63893 180.632 0.871948C178.921 0 176.68 0 172.2 0H17.8C13.3196 0 11.0794 0 9.36808 0.871948C7.86278 1.63893 6.63893 2.86278 5.87195 4.36808Z" fill="#E06956" />
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is to swap the order of the path and text elements so the text element is drawn on top of the path. After that you just need to position the text where you want it and ensure it has a fill colour so you can see it.

```html
<svg width="185" height="89" viewBox="0 0 185  89" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.87195 4.36808C5 6.07937 5 8.31958 5 12.8V27.4268L0.481487 32.6984C-0.160496 33.4474 -0.160496 34.5526 0.481487 35.3016L5 40.5732V76.2C5 80.6804 5 82.9206 5.87195 84.6319C6.63893 86.1372 7.86278 87.3611 9.36808 88.1281C11.0794 89 13.3196 89 17.8 89H172.2C176.68 89 178.921 89 180.632 88.1281C182.137 87.3611 183.361 86.1372 184.128 84.6319C185 82.9206 185 80.6804 185 76.2V12.8C185 8.31958 185 6.07937 184.128 4.36808C183.361 2.86278 182.137 1.63893 180.632 0.871948C178.921 0 176.68 0 172.2 0H17.8C13.3196 0 11.0794 0 9.36808 0.871948C7.86278 1.63893 6.63893 2.86278 5.87195 4.36808Z" fill="#E06956" />
    <text y="43" x="61" fill="white">hello</text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: What if you add long text? How can it fit in a svg and automatic cut to another line when hit the end of the svg ?

Comment: SVG does not have any kind of built in automatic cutting. You'd have to implement something in javascript to do that by creating additional tspan elements and positioning them.